# Robo 3T SaslFailed

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, robo3t

I am trying to connect to my Azure CosmoDB

This is the error I get: **SSL connection failure: SaslFailed**

[image]

I cant seem to find any information about this error. When I try to login using Studio 3T with the same login inputs, it works (however, this one is not free).

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: What is the version of Robo3T that you are using?

Comment: @SiddheshVethe I have tried with version 1.1.1 and 1.2, and same error in both :(

Comment: Experienced the same problem. Password in connection string has base64 encoding. But in my copied password it was also url encoded and ended with %3D%3D symbols, replaced with == accorgingly and it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did't reproduce your issue when I accessed to my Azure cosmos db(mongodb). Please refer to my Connection settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***query result:***

[image]

Comment: I feel like these are the steps I have tried 10 times already, but for whatever reason, its working now. Thank you! :)